# Ubuntu 22.04 locks system while in use

Tags: video, lock

Running on a Dell 5680, Ubuntu installed by Dell (computer came with it).

All settings that I can find are set for no locking, no screen saver, no sleep.  It can be used for no more than 15 seconds before locking, even while actively typing/mousing.

Oddly enough, this doesn't happen all the time.  Sometimes (rarely) a reboot will bring it to normal use.  Sometimes closing the lid and reopening it seems to cause normal behavior.

External keyboard/mouse or internal kb/trackpad makes no difference.  I've not used it with a connected monitor, just the laptop's display.

Any ideas?  I don't think it's a hardware fault in the computer, as I have three of these that behave the same way.  A video driver, perhaps?  Though they're supposedly up to date...